# how to deep merge arrays of helm named templates

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to merge 2 named templates.

In simplified form it looks like this:

```
{{- define "common.t1" -}}
a1: "t1-a1"
a2: "t1-a2"
b1:
  c1: t1-b1-c1
  c2: t1-b1-c2
d1:
  - name: container1
    e1: t1-d1-e1
    e2: t1-d1-e2
  - name: container2
    
{{- end -}}

{{- define "this.t2" -}}
a1: "t2-a1"
a3: "t2-a3"
b1:
  c1: t2-b1-c1
  c3: t2-b1-c3 
d1:
  - name: container1
    e1: t2-d1-e1
    e3: t2-d1-e3
  - name: container3
{{- end -}}

{{- $t1 := fromYaml (include "common.t1" .) -}}
{{- $t2 := fromYaml (include "this.t2" .) -}}
{{ toYaml (merge $t2 $t1) }}
```

The result is

```
a1: t2-a1
a2: t1-a2
a3: t2-a3
b1:
  c1: t2-b1-c1
  c2: t1-b1-c2
  c3: t2-b1-c3
d1:
- e1: t2-d1-e1
  e3: t2-d1-e3
  name: container1
- name: container3
```

the d1 array objects are fully overriden by t2 template, but i want it to be merged with d1 array from the t1.

What i want to get is

```
a1: t2-a1
a2: t1-a2
a3: t2-a3
b1:
  c1: t2-b1-c1
  c2: t1-b1-c2
  c3: t2-b1-c3
d1:
- e1: t2-d1-e1
  e2: t1-d1-e2
  e3: t2-d1-e3
  name: container1
- name: container2
- name: container3
```

The purpose of merging is to have templates in common library chart that may be extended by templates in consumer chart and simplify development and maintainance of several dozens of helm charts.

For example put all common kube deployment yaml boilerplate into base template and then just write

```
{{ magicMerge "common.deployment" "mychart548.deployment" . }}
{{- define "mychart548.deployment" -}}
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ include "common.names.name" . }}
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: {{ include "common.names.envConfigmapName" . }}
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ include "common.names.fullname" . }}-postgress
                  key: postgres-password
{{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible without writing your own merge function in Helm template code, which will be unpleasant.

At a low level, the Helm `merge` function actually comes from an extension library called [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/).  The [Sprig `merge` function](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/eaeb5ac769579fa931de26f89dfb70c9daf228cc/dict.go#L90-L98) delegates to another Go library, [Mergo](https://github.com/imdario/mergo).  At a code level there happens to be a config options for merging Go slices (lists), but there are only two options: append one to the other, or try to merge each corresponding pair of elements.  Sprig, and therefore Helm, uses the latter (default) option, and therefore what I'd expect to see from your example is that, inside `d1`, in the second list item, in the pair of maps, in the `name:` key, the different strings `container1` and `container2` can't be merged.

More abstractly: you're trying to merge two lists by deep-comparing the individual items for equality and taking their union; you don't want to do a deeper merge.  That's a little more application-specific knowledge than a generic `merge` function can have.

If it will be exactly two lists like this, and you're trying to output the result and not process it further (or use the `include ... | toYaml` trick you have already), then one possible approach is to

1. Write out the first list as-is
2. Also convert the first list to a list of serialized strings
3. For each item in the second list,

   1. Serialize it
   2. Check to see if it's in the first list (serialized)
   3. If not, emit it

```
{{/*- Convert a list to a list of JSON-serialized strings. */}}
{{- define "list-to-string-list" -}}
[
{{- range $index, $item := . -}}
{{- if ne $index 0 }},{{- end -}}
{{- toJson $item | toJson -}}
{{- end -}}
]
{{- end -}}

{{- define "merge-d1" -}}
{{- $first := index . 0 -}}
{{- $second := index . 1 -}}
{{/*- emit the first list -*/}}
{{- toYaml $first -}}
{{/*- index the first list -*/}}
{{- $firstStrings := include "list-to-string-list" $first | fromJson -}}
{{/*- for each item in the second list... -*/}}
{{- range $second -}}
{{/*- ...if it's not in the indexed list... -*/}}
{{- if not (has (toJson .) $firstStrings) -*/}}
{{/*- ...emit it too -*/}}
- {{ . | toYaml | nindent 2 | trim }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

d1:
{{ include "merge-d1" (list $first.d1 $second.d1) | indent 2 }}
```

If you're starting to write logic like this, consider whether writing it in a Kubernetes operator in a more mainstream language like Go might be more maintainable long-term.

Comment: thanks for explaining why it wouldn work in a way that i wanted.